# Find the nearest quarter on numpy array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array that  contains numbers with a 0.25 step. So a part of this array is [-38.25, -38,-37.75, -37.5]. I want to be able to find the nearest and lowest quarter to any number.

For example if the input is -37.778 then the closest quarters would be -37.75 and -38 and the lowest would be -38. So the output should be -38 or even better the corresponding index for -38.

I do it manually with approximations and later using np.searchsorted but I thought there must be a better way. Also the array is 400 elements long so I'm not sure is the best to do it this way.

Comment: If you have -37.778, why would it give you -38 when -37.75 is closer?

Comment: @jared yes -37.75 is closer but i need the lowest in value from the 2 elements that are the nearest to the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

From the description the indices can be calculated.  Multiply by 8 and convert to an integer to get the index * 2.  This will be even if the nearest is round down and odd if the nearest is to round up.

```
import numpy as np

threshold = np.arange( -38., -34.9, 0.25 )
threshold
# array([-38.  , -37.75, -37.5 , -37.25, -37.  , -36.75, -36.5 , -36.25,
#        -36.  , -35.75, -35.5 , -35.25, -35.  ])

np.random.seed( 123 )
arr = (np.random.rand( 10 )*3-38.).round(2) # Some values to try. 
# Rounded to print arr on a line.

index_x2 = np.floor(( ( arr-threshold.min() ) * 8 )).astype( np.int64 )
# index * 2 = (arr-lowest threshold ) * 8 as an integer

floor_index = index_x2 // 2   # The threshold index always rounded down.  

nearest_index = ( index_x2 + 1 ) // 2  # The threshold index rounded to nearest.

print( arr )                                  
# [-35.91 -37.14 -37.32 -36.35 -35.84 -36.73 -35.06 -35.95 -36.56 -36.82 ]

print( floor_index )
# [ 8  3  2  6  8  5 11  8  5  4]

print( nearest_index )
# [ 8  3  3  7  9  5 12  8  6  5]

print( threshold[ floor_index ] )
# [-36.   -37.25 -37.5  -36.5  -36.   -36.75 -35.25 -36.   -36.75 -37.  ]

print( threshold[ nearest_index ])
# [-36.   -37.25 -37.25 -36.25 -35.75 -36.75 -35.   -36.   -36.5  -36.75]
```